# HTML5 Date Picker - Remove Date Arrows

Tags: javascript, angular, html

I am using Angular. I am curious to how I can remove these arrows:

[image]

Also, if its possible to click the date picker box(Where mm/dd/yyyy is) and allow it to show the Date Selector instead of clicking the far right arrow.

Comment: can you please open JSFiddle?

Comment: I mean its just the basic HTML5 Form. I have no additional properties on it.

<form>
  Birthday:
  <input type="date" name="bday">
</form>

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with jquery here is a demo (I couldn't get it to work in the snippet)

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6zqwx4s9/)

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
  });
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<body>
<form>
    <input id="datepicker" />Choose a date
</form>
</body>
```

You can resize the datepicker by doing something like

```
div.ui-datepicker{
   font-size:10px;
}
```

Comment: I have created this, I am now looking to add an event when I click on the box it shows the Date Picker. http://plnkr.co/edit/wE4GmFtXvNII2iZzEe0s?p=preview

Comment: that's not what you asked. the one that i created pops up when you click the box anyway, why don't you use it?

Comment: My apologizes, but I do not want to use j Query, the app is running off Angular.

Comment: well that was important information, you should mention that in your question

Comment: This simply replaces the native HTML5 date selector with a library’s (jQuery UI). It might work for the OP, but doesn’t actually answer the question.

Comment: @HereticMonkey My answer was a suggested solution to the original question [posted over 3 years ago and answered also in 2015] . As you can see from the comments, the question was later edited, but I left it for someone else to make further suggestions. As you may be aware, stack overflow is NOT a code-writing service. [and if you're going to downvote, downvote the question that lacks a minimal and verifiable example ]

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it does this across all browsers; narrow down where you see this and where you don't want to see this; and then do something like the below but specific to the browser your targeting.

```
input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator{
    display: none;
}
```